# What am I missing converting cartesian to polar coordinate system?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I've got the equation $ x^2+y^2=2x $. By looking at the [graph of that function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20x%5E2%2by%5E2=2x), I know that it is equivalent to $ r=2\cos{\theta} $ ([graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20r=2%20cos%20theta)).

However, if I convert it by substituting in using the equations $ x = \cos{\theta} $ and $ r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $, I get $ r^2 = 2 \cos{\theta} $.

I'm sure it's something obvious, but what am I missing that gives me this incorrect answer?

Comment: We have $x=r\cos\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the $r$ on the other side:  $r^2 = 2r\cos \theta$.

Comment: gah thanks, gotta remember formulas correctly.